# Bidirectional relationship ManyToMany symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I need help for my problem.
When add the relationship ManyToMany to the php script this return when validate the relationship.
This is my scripts:

```
   class Post implements ResourceInterface, TranslatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $important;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tags",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $tags;
}
```

And

```
class Tag implements ResourceInterface, TranslatableInterface
{
    use TranslatableTrait {
        __construct as private initializeTranslationsCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Post", 
    mappedBy="tags")
     */
    private $posts;
}
```

The error is:

Mapping

> [FAIL] The entity-class AppBundle\Entity\Tag mapping is invalid:  *
>   The field AppBundle\Entity\Tag#posts is on the inverse side of a bi-
>   directional relationship, but the specified mappedBy association on
>   the   target-entity AppBundle\Entity\Post#tags does not contain the
>   required   'inversedBy="posts"' attribute.

Comment: This is a ManyToMany Unidirectionnal relation. You wrote a bi directionnal mapping. See [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

Answer (score 0):

Hello use symfony maker

. /bin/console make:entity Post

For the field name enter 'tags' and for the type enter 'relation' . Then give the related tags entity name. Shoud be Tag. Choose the manytomany relation and enter. Like this you should never have relation issue :-).  Even if the entity exist already.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the mapping of the tags attribute in the post entity should be like this:

```
class Post implements ResourceInterface, TranslatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $important;
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Tag", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tags",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $tags;
}
```

I hope I've helped :)